# Binary tree,return the parent of the node

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree

I try to write a function which return the parent of the value node.The createAB function works,but i don't know to iterate the binary tree elements.How to make recursively call?.Please help me.

```
 ifstream f("store.txt");//store.txt:10 7 8 0 0 0 13 9 0 11 0 0 12 0 0
    struct elem {
        int inf;
        elem* st;
        elem* dr;
    };
    //this function create the binary tree
    void createAB(elem*& p) {
        int n;
        f >> n;
        if (n!=0) {
            p = new elem;
            p->inf = n;
            createAB(p->st);
            createAB(p->dr);
        }
        else 
            p = NULL;
    }
    `

        elem* parent(elem* rad, int n) {//my function,doesn't work
        if (rad == NULL)
            return NULL;
        else
            if (rad->st->inf == n || rad->dr->inf == n) 
                return rad;//return the element
            else {
                return parent(rad->st, n);//here is a problem
                return parent(rad->dr, n);
            }
    }
      10
   7       13
 8       9    12
           11
node 12 => parent 13
node 8 => parent 7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by sebi519, you need to check that `rad->st` and `rad->dr` are not `NULL`.

But as you correctly commented the main problem here is in the return statements. The problem is that the second line is never executed as the first line already returns from the function.

```
return parent(rad->st, n);//This returns and the next line is not executed
return parent(rad->dr, n);
```

You need to save the result of the first call and check if it was successful and if not then do the second call:

```
elem* result = parent(rad->st,n);
if (result != NULL)
  return result;
else
  return parent(rad->dr,n);
```

Full corrected function:

```
elem* parent(elem* rad, int n) {
  if (rad == NULL)
    return NULL;
  else
    if ( (rad->st!=NULL && rad->st->inf == n) || (rad->dr!=NULL) && (rad->dr->inf == n)){
      return rad;//return the element
    }
    else {
      elem* result= parent(rad->st, n);
      if (result!=NULL){
        return result;
      }
      else{
        return parent(rad->dr, n);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: @paulc I added the full function. At least it works for me.

Comment: That's probably worth of a new question, but one possibility is to follow the logic of breath first graph traversal. Push the root node to queue and then loop until queue is empty. In the loop get the first element of queue, check if one of the children is in the searched nodes, if yes return the node, otherwise push the children into the queue.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if `rad->st` and `rad->dr` is null before using `rad->st->inf` and `rad->dr->inf`.